# How do you fix this for loop to validate a username?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

This is for my GCSE coursework and I can't figure out what I have done wrong in the code.
I have tried changing the type of CSV file opening (changing it from w to r to r+) but the for loop is not being executed.

It is supposed to check if the username is in the CSV file and if it is, it should be accepted, else, they should be able to re-enter.

The usernames in the CSV files are Test01 and Test02

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import random
Player1 = 0
Player2 = 0
Again = True
File = open("Dice Game.csv","r+")
File.write("Test01" + "\n")
File.write("Test02" + "\n")

while Again == True:
    Input1 = str(input("Player 1, please input your username."))
    Open = open("Dice Game.csv", "r")
    File = csv.reader(File)
    for row in File:
        User = row[0]
        if User == Input1:
            print("That username is not authourised, please re-enter.")
            Again = True
            break
        else:
            Again = False
```

Comment: Add a tag for the programming language you use.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is having your logic backward:

```
    if User == Input1:
        print("That username is not authourised, please re-enter.")
```

If the user name matches, the user *is* authorized!  Switch to `!=` here and move the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . . . I suggest you get familiar using with statement, I noticed you don't close your files

```
import csv
import random

with open('DiceGame.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=",")
    writer.writerow(['Test01', 'Test02'])

again = True
while(again):
    _input = str(input("Player 1, please enter  your username: "))
    with open("DiceGame.csv", 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            if _input in row:
                # Username is valid
                again = False
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid username, please try again.")
```